# Not able to show a border between rows in an unorderded list

Tags: html, css

I want to create a popup using  unordered lists, which gives an overall table feel.
The part of the table code is :

```
<div class="list-wrapper">              
<div class="row">
                <ul >
                    <li class="col-xs-1"><img src="./details_files/experience.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2" ><strong>Total Experience</strong></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3" id= "url1">7 Year(s)</li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3">7 Year(s)</li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3">7 Year(s)</li>
                </ul>
</div>          

<div class = "row">         
                <ul>
                    <li class="col-xs-1"><img src="./details_files/clients.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2"><strong>Client Served</strong></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3" id= "url1">2028</li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3">7 Year(s)</li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3">7 Year(s)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

I have used CSS :

.list-wrapper ul li { display: table-cell;

```
vertical-align: top;
width: 185px;
font-size: 20px;
border-right: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
border-bottom: 5px solid #E6E6E6;

padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10000px;
margin-bottom: -10000px;
background-color: #FFF;

}
```

This is what my popup looks like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Wz4.png

Now between every line I want a border. 
I.E between TOTAL EXPERIANCES and CLIENT SERVED I want a border.

to explain the css i used padding-bottom and margin bottom to auto resize all the rows to share a common border. Without this code i would have a popup as follow : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIc00.png

### My goal is to have a common border between rows and have a table feel. Please ask questions.

EDIT :

The solution provided by humble rumble solves the border problem, However i want individual cells to resize its height and still have a single row border

IE for this :

```
<div class = "row">


                <ul>
                    <li class="col-xs-1"><img src="./details_files/services.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2" ><strong>Services</strong></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3" id= "url1">
                            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Bar" class="inlineBlock">Bar</a>
                            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=DJ" class="inlineBlock">DJ</a>
                            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Ghazal" class="inlineBlock">Ghazal</a>
                            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Eleculicity%20Back-up" class="inlineBlock">Eleculicity Back-up</a>
                            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Air%20Conditioned" class="inlineBlock">Air Conditioned</a></li>
                <li class="col-xs-3">null</li>
                <li class="col-xs-3">null</li>
<!--                <li class="22%">null</li> -->

                </ul>
</div>
```

BAR, DJ, GHAZAL should all resize the cell height automatically

Comment: yes , can you run me on what changes you did ? 
EDIT : It works but you predefined the height of the cells are static I want them to resize the height, and still maintain a single horizontal border.

Comment: please respond to the edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `col-*` and `row` classes and just use `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`. Then remove the padding and margins. The divs will naturally take the same height once the `col-*` classes are removed.

```css
.list-wrapper ul {
    display: table-row;
}
.list-wrapper ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-right: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="./details_files/services.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><strong>Services</strong></li>
        <li id="url1">
            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Bar" class="inlineBlock">Bar</a>
            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=DJ" class="inlineBlock">DJ</a>
            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Ghazal" class="inlineBlock">Ghazal</a>
            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Eleculicity%20Back-up" class="inlineBlock">Eleculicity Back-up</a>
            <a href="http://www.eventila.com/eventila-web/search/restaurant/?services=Air%20Conditioned" class="inlineBlock">Air Conditioned</a>
        </li>
        <li>null</li>
        <li>null</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```